# How to Convert a Date Span to Monthly Records using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple date spans for the user over a period of few months, I would like to split each span to multiple rows by month and year(default to first day of the month) for which user has been active during the span period. Active user will have future end date records to be split up until the current month and year

Existing Data

| ID | Start date | end date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2019-01-01 | 2019-03-31 |
| 1234 | 2019-09-18 | 2020-01-31 |
| 1234 | 2022-11-15 | 2025-01-31 |

Tried to place the below date month query into the spans

```
  Select Top 500 mmdd=cast (dateadd(Month,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)),'2019-01-01') as date)
  
          From master..spt_values n1 
          order by 1 asc
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT

| ID | active month |
| --- | --- |
| 1234 | 2019-01-01 |
| 1234 | 2019-02-01 |
| 1234 | 2019-03-01 |
| 1234 | 2019-09-01 |
| 1234 | 2019-10-01 |
| 1234 | 2019-11-01 |
| 1234 | 2019-12-01 |
| 1234 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1234 | 2022-11-01 |
| 1234 | 2022-12-01 |
| 1234 | 2023-01-01 |

Comment: Invest in a calendar table

Answer (score 0):

Larnu is on the right track. One of the easiest ways I've found is to create a calendar table or a function (which can effectively do the same thing).

Try this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udfCalendar] 
(   
   @StartDate Date,
   @EndDate Date
)
RETURNS @Calendar TABLE (ID int, DateValue DateTime, DayValue int, MonthValue int, YearValue int)
AS

BEGIN
   WHILE @StartDate < @EndDate
   BEGIN
       INSERT @Calendar
       SELECT --like 20190101, 1/1/2019, 1, 1, 2019
           YEAR (@StartDate) * 10000 + MONTH (@StartDate) * 100 + Day (@StartDate) AS ID,
           @StartDate AS DateValue,
           DATEPART (dd, @StartDate) AS DayValue,
           DATEPART (mm, @StartDate) AS MonthValue,
           DATEPART (yy, @StartDate) AS YearValue;
    
       SET @StartDate = DateAdd(m, 1, @StartDate);
   END

   RETURN;
END
```

Then you can join to it

```
Select n1.ID, cal.DateValue as ActiveMonth
From master..spt_values n1 inner join 
    dbo.udfCalendar('1/1/2019', '1/1/2023') cal 
    On cal.DateValue Between n1.StartDate and n1.EndDate
Order By DateValue
```

Comment: Right idea, but likely to perform poorly since you have to build the table row by row each time you need it. If it'll be used frequently, just build a permanent table. And/or, Google "itzik ban-gan tally table" for the perhaps optimal way to generate data useful for these kinds of tables.

Comment: It should perform okay for short periods of time, like the one shown. 2 years = 24 rows = light. Which is why the function takes a min-date & max-date, to keep the range narrow instead of rounding to centuries or something. If you need decades or more, definitely make a table.

Comment: Frequency of use can also be a factor. Once an hour, even once a minute could be fine, but a hundred times a second can add up quickly. Much depends on how it will be used "in the field", and we rarely hear that on SO.